# conditional sequence across rows in a new column

Tags: r, dplyr, time-series

If there's a "6" in `df$a`, I'd like `1:9` from the previous September to next May, to be in a new column, shown here as `df$b`, with `NA` as the rest.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
date <- c("2/29/1940","3/31/1940","4/30/1940","5/31/1940","6/30/1940","7/31/1940","8/31/1940","9/30/1940","10/31/1940","11/30/1940","12/31/1940","1/31/1941","2/28/1941",
       "3/31/1941","4/30/1941","5/31/1941","6/30/1941","7/31/1941","8/31/1941","9/30/1941","10/31/1941","11/30/1941", "12/31/1941","1/31/1942","2/28/1942","3/31/1942",
       "4/30/1942","5/31/1942", "6/30/1942","7/31/1942","8/31/1942","9/30/1942","10/31/1942","11/30/1942","12/31/1942","1/31/1943","2/28/1943","3/31/1943","4/30/1943",
       "5/31/1943","6/30/1943","7/31/1943", "8/31/1943","9/30/1943")
a <- c("NA","NA","NA","NA","NA","NA","NA","NA","NA","NA","NA","NA",6,"NA","NA","NA","NA","NA","NA","NA","NA","NA","NA","NA","NA","NA","NA","NA","NA","NA","NA","NA","NA",
   "NA","NA","NA","NA","NA","NA","NA","NA","NA","NA","NA")
df <- data.frame(date, a)
df %<>% mutate(date = mdy(date), a)

df:
date        a   b
2/29/1940   NA  NA
3/31/1940   NA  NA
4/30/1940   NA  NA
5/31/1940   NA  NA
6/30/1940   NA  NA
7/31/1940   NA  NA
8/31/1940   NA  NA
9/30/1940   NA  1
10/31/1940  NA  2
11/30/1940  NA  3
12/31/1940  NA  4
1/31/1941   NA  5
2/28/1941   6   6
3/31/1941   NA  7
4/30/1941   NA  8
5/31/1941   NA  9
6/30/1941   NA  NA
7/31/1941   NA  NA
8/31/1941   NA  NA
9/30/1941   NA  NA
10/31/1941  NA  NA
11/30/1941  NA  NA
12/31/1941  NA  NA
1/31/1942   NA  NA
2/28/1942   NA  NA
3/31/1942   NA  NA
4/30/1942   NA  NA
5/31/1942   NA  NA
6/30/1942   NA  NA
7/31/1942   NA  NA
8/31/1942   NA  NA
9/30/1942   NA  NA
10/31/1942  NA  NA
11/30/1942  NA  NA
12/31/1942  NA  NA
1/31/1943   NA  NA
2/28/1943   NA  NA
3/31/1943   NA  NA
4/30/1943   NA  NA
5/31/1943   NA  NA
6/30/1943   NA  NA
7/31/1943   NA  NA
8/31/1943   NA  NA
9/30/1943   NA  NA
```

For more context, I have a hundred years or so of monthly data in a data frame and I'm looking for an efficient way to produce the third column given the first two columns, to process/visualize other data not shown.  Only sometimes there is a 6 for February in `df$a`. When so, I'd like the previous September through the next May to be populated as shown in a new column (I'm looking to produce `df$b`). I tried some clumsy ways, mostly by a bunch of lines with variations of  `mutate()` , `lag()` , and `lead()` but have a good feeling there's more direct routes.

thank you,

dave

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do. Also, could you provide a subset of your data frame for us to load directly into our R sessions, and maybe an example of what the desired output would be? That would help make the problem reproducible. Thanks :)

Comment: If everything is monthly like the sample data you posted implies, you could do: `df[Reduce(c, lapply(which(df$a == 6), function(x) (x-5):(x+3))), "b"] <- 1:9`

Comment: Or even: `df[rep(which(df$a == 6), each = 9) + ((1:9) - 6), "b"] <- 1:9`

Comment: BTW: `c("NA", 6, "NA")` does not keep the 6 as a number. Perhaps `c(NA, 6, NA)` (no quotes) is what you'd prefer?

Comment: Thank you all!! It turns out in one case I have, that there's a `6` in the first February as the 5th row after starting in `Oct-1921`.  It's throwing an error, I think because there aren't sufficient rows above to accomodate the `1:9`. Might there be an easy adjustment for cases when the `6` is near the very beginning or end of the timeseries, to just fill whatever is available? Much thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution using `case_when`, `lead`, and `lag` from [dplyr](/questions/tagged/dplyr). It is not the most concise solution, but it will work when 6 is close to the edge.

```
library(tidyverse)

df2 <- df %>%
  mutate(b = case_when(
    lead(a, n = 5L) == 6     ~1,
    lead(a, n = 4L) == 6     ~2,
    lead(a, n = 3L) == 6     ~3,
    lead(a, n = 2L) == 6     ~4,
    lead(a, n = 1L) == 6     ~5,
                  a == 6     ~6,
     lag(a, n = 1L) == 6     ~7,
     lag(a, n = 2L) == 6     ~8,
     lag(a, n = 3L) == 6     ~9,
    TRUE                     ~NA_real_
  ))
```

**DATA**

Notice that I changed the way you specified `NA` in the column A.

```
library(lubridate)
date <- c("2/29/1940","3/31/1940","4/30/1940","5/31/1940","6/30/1940","7/31/1940","8/31/1940","9/30/1940","10/31/1940","11/30/1940","12/31/1940","1/31/1941","2/28/1941",
          "3/31/1941","4/30/1941","5/31/1941","6/30/1941","7/31/1941","8/31/1941","9/30/1941","10/31/1941","11/30/1941", "12/31/1941","1/31/1942","2/28/1942","3/31/1942",
          "4/30/1942","5/31/1942", "6/30/1942","7/31/1942","8/31/1942","9/30/1942","10/31/1942","11/30/1942","12/31/1942","1/31/1943","2/28/1943","3/31/1943","4/30/1943",
          "5/31/1943","6/30/1943","7/31/1943", "8/31/1943","9/30/1943")
a <- c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA , 6, NA , NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA , NA , NA , NA , NA , NA , NA,
       NA, NA, NA , NA , NA , NA , NA , NA , NA , NA , NA)
df <- data.frame(date, a)
df %<>% mutate(date = mdy(date), a)
```